# Set jquery code to body page onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have this jquery  code which i searched on the net. im new to jquery. the code need to click the button to execute. my question is how is the code to execute this jquery on page load.

```
<button id="notification-trigger" class="progress-button">
                        <span class="content">Show Notification</span>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                    </button>
<script>
        (function() {
            var bttn = document.getElementById( 'notification-trigger' );

            // make sure..
            bttn.disabled = false;

            bttn.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                // simulate loading (for demo purposes only)
                classie.add( bttn, 'active' );
                setTimeout( function() {

                    classie.remove( bttn, 'active' );

                    // create the notification
                    var notification = new NotificationFx({
                        message : '<div class="ns-thumb"><img src="img/user1.jpg"/></div><div class="ns-content"><p>Welcome, Nixxx!</p></div>',
                        layout : 'other',
                        ttl : 6000,
                        effect : 'thumbslider',
                        type : 'notice', // notice, warning, error or success
                        onClose : function() {
                            bttn.disabled = false;
                        }
                    });

                    // show the notification
                    notification.show();

                }, 1200 );

                // disable the button (for demo purposes only)
                this.disabled = true;
            } );
        })();
</script>
```

i want something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    $("#div1").fadeToggle();
    $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

please help thanks!

(Edited i include the button that needs to click before the script execute.) i want this code to execute everytime i load/refresh the page and not by clicking the button. thanks for the help!

Comment: I think while copying the code, you forgot to copy the dollar $ sign at the beginning of function. :-)

Comment: curious what problems you encounter, code should work as shown in second version although `onload` is not preferred jQuery approach

Comment: the script code says i need to click button before the code execute

Comment: This is what im doing the thumbnail notification. http://tympanus.net/Development/NotificationStyles/other-thumbslider.html

Answer (score 3):

Please use the following code. It works the same as the onload() function of Vanilla Javascript.

```
<script>
    // $(function(){}); Wrapper acts as the document.ready of vanilla javascript
    $(function(){

      //call myfunction() onload;
      myFunction();

      //functions to execute goes in here
      function myFunction() {
           $("#div1").fadeToggle();
           $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
           $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);

           //call button action instead of click
           btnFunction();
      }

   var bttn = document.getElementById( 'notification-trigger' );

   bttn.disabled = false;

   function btnFunction() {

   classie.add( bttn, 'active' );
   setTimeout( function() {

        classie.remove( bttn, 'active' );

        var notification = new NotificationFx({
            message : '<div class="ns-thumb"><img src="img/user1.jpg"/></div><div class="ns-content">   <p>Welcome, Nikko Zabala!</p></div>',
            layout : 'other',
            ttl : 6000,
            effect : 'thumbslider',
            type : 'notice', // notice, warning, error or success
            onClose : function() {
                bttn.disabled = false;
           }
    });
       notification.show();

   }, 1200 );

   };

   });
</script>
```

Comment: Here's a slightly more verbose yet readable version: `$(document).ready(function () {});`

Comment: how i will set write it on <body></body> ?

Comment: how i will write that code like this <body onload="myFunction()">

Comment: yap but how to load that script code in page onload??

Comment: Modified my answer I made it as simple as possible. Basically just modify the myFunction function() to how you want things to run. But the idea of how to run it onload is there

Comment: This is what im doing the thumbnail notification. tympanus.net/Development/NotificationStyles/ i want the notification to show everytime i load the page. not by clicking the button

Comment: Try the new answer if it works. I'm not exactly sure if it would work because I haven't tried the effect on the link you sent yet.  But the thought of onload() is on my code.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      myFunction()
        // put your code here;
    });



  function myFunction() {
 // your code
      }
function btnFunction(){
// your code
}

</script>
```